# Cons of letting unauthenticated users access database in FIrebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

What are the cons of setting security rules of `Firebase` database such that **unauthenticated users could also access the database**? **In what ways can the database be attacked?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all firebase databases are accessible via the id of the project:

For example:
you could browse the Database from any computer using the project id:
'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/.json'
(GET request)

we could also make POST PATCH And DELETE Requests to your database and clear it out!

```
curl -X POST -d '{"myData" : "in", "your" : "Database!"}' \
  'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/yourHacked.json'
```

If you have security rules in place, this functionality will still work if you send Auth tokens with the requests. (So it becomes safer with every security rule you add).

With security rules you can make sure that only the data owner can edit Or read it:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Notes": {
      "$userId": {
        // grant read/write permission to the owner of this note
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid", 
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Attackers May use your database as their own causing you a lot a traffic, data corruption / Mining, Money (Usage Quotas).

See the following reference for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But to access database from outside the app, one would require the URL of the database, which only the owner would be having, right? Also, if we create such flow of data in app such that user only provides the information, and then app validated this data and decides where to write the data, would that safeguard database? For example, if the user fills details in his profile in app, the app can validate the data and then store data at the current user's node in the database, hence the user would only be able to write at his own node in the database. Would this work?

Comment: The Url can be obtained from the .APK / GitHub / sniffed over the air, Or from debugging the network requests of your app. The only thing that can Protect you are Security rules that only the owner may write his own data. Or Other Privileged users that you trust. like the following: {
  "rules": {
    "Notes": {
      "$userId": {
        // grant read/write permission to the owner of this note
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$userId === auth.uid", 
        ".read": "$userId === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Hey, one more thing.. is Anonymous Authentication safe for letting access to database or does it also have the vulnerabilities of Unauthenticated access to database? @TomerBu

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that a user can flood your database with data or read until you run out of free quota (if you just use the free plan). I would call that some sort of denial-of-service (DoS) attack.

Obviously if you pay for it and don't specify any maximum cost limits then it might get costly for you. I've not paid for Firebase so far and don't know if you can set cost limits. Anyway your service/app would be down.

In case your app allows one's user data to be overwritten by another user that would be another bad thing but that gets more into a badly designed app. Whereas the previous attack vector could not be entirely avoided when e.g. you run a email subscription service on a website to get potential customers. You would need some other security measures against a DoS attack.

I don't think it can get a lot worse :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Another thing, if we create such a flow of data such that the user only provides the information, and then the app validated this data and decides where to write the data, would that safeguard our database? For example, if the user fills in the details in his profile, the app can validate the data and then store this data at the current user's node in the database, hence the user would only be able to write at his own node in the database. Would this work? @Ewald B.

Comment: What you're talking about is client-side validation but that doesn't completely safeguard from somebody circumventing your apps validation mechanism. If the attacker has your API key and the URL of your Firebase app then there's nothing that prevents him to do anything that the database rules allow him (in your case no rules at all). It's best  to be as restrictive as possible.

Comment: Hey, one more thing.. is Anonymous Authentication safe for letting access to database or does it also have the vulnerabilities of Unauthenticated access to database? @Edwald B.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "anonymous authentication"? Having the same rules for all users?

Comment: No, there is a form of authentication in firebase which does not require the user to fill in any details. I dont know the exact working of it it.    https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth @Ewald B.

Comment: As far as I understand it is a mechanism to allow users use your app's features without signing in with some special credentials. An user ID is created. That doesn't differ in any way from a normal authenticated user. So it's equally "secure".

Comment: OK. Thanks! @Edwald B.